# Recovering radioButton selections in Shiny - using modules and lapply

Tags: r, module, shiny, lapply

I am dynamically generating a set of radio buttons based on an input file with questions and possible answers.  I have discovered that I can do this with lapply.  It has taken awhile, but I think I have the code correctly constructed to make the buttons and read the results when a selection is made.

But I cannot get the results out of the module, and I am not sure why.

Here is example code:

ui.R:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(
  fluidRow(
    questListInput("occList1")
  )
)
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)

source("global.R")                      #Sources the modules used in the app

questionSet <<- read.csv("./Data/QuestData.csv")
occQuestSet <- questionSet[questionSet$Category == "Occurrence",]

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    occAnswer1 <- callModule(questList,"occList1",occQuestSet,"Occur1")
  })    

  output$answerseT <- renderText(answerSeto1())
})
```

the modules are in global.R

```
questListInput <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)

  uiOutput(ns("c1"))

}

questList <- function(input, output, session, q, l) {

  ###This function requires the type of question to be specified

  #  ns <- session$ns

  output$c1 <- renderUI({
    lapply(1:nrow(q),
           function(i) {

             createLabel <- function(name,j) {
               paste0(name,": ",q$Element.Question[j],sep = "")
             }

             labelQ <- createLabel(q[i,]$QID,i)


             createOptions <- function() {
               as.matrix(q[i,5:length(q)])
             }
             tagList(
               tags$hr(style="border-color: darkblue;"),
               h4((paste0(labelQ))),
               radioButtons(session$ns(paste0(l,i)), "Please Select:", choices = c(createOptions()))
             )
           }
    )
  })

  answer <- NULL

  observe({
    lapply(1:nrow(q), 
           function(i) {
             answer[[paste0(l,i)]] <- input[[paste0(l,i)]] 
             #input[[paste0(l,i)]] 
             print(answer)
           }
     )
   })
  print("Inside the Module")
 # print(input$c1)
  # return(
  #  list(
  #    answer1 = reactive({paste0(l,1)})
  #  )
  # )
}
```

after all of this, if I turn on the print function inside the observe lapply, I can see the three selections made by radio button selection.  If I change a selection, this list of three updates.

But I cannot figure out how to access the result so that I can use it outside the module!

This is the data that is read in  from QuestionSet.csv

Category,QID,Element,Element Question,Low,Medium,High
Consequence,C01,Type1,Problem 1,Solution 1,Solution 2,Solution 3
Consequence,C02,Type2,Problem 2,Solution 1,Solution 2,Solution 3
Consequence,C03,Type3,Problem 3,Solution 1,Solution 2,Solution 3
Consequence,C04,Type4,Problem 4,Solution 1,Solution 2,Solution 3
Detection,D01,Type5,Problem 5,Solution 1,Solution 2,Solution 3
Detection,D02,Type6,Problem 6,Solution 1,Solution 2,Solution 3
Detection,D03,Type7,Problem 7,Solution 1,Solution 2,Solution 3
Detection,D04,Type8,Problem 8,Solution 1,Solution 2,Solution 3
Detection,D05,Type9,Problem 9,Solution 1,Solution 2,Solution 3
Occurrence,O01,Type10,Problem 10,Solution 1,Solution 2,Solution 3
Occurrence,O02,Type11,Problem 11,Solution 1,Solution 2,Solution 3
Occurrence,O03,Type12,Problem 12,Solution 1,Solution 2,Solution 3

Comment: The problem seems to be with the lapply I am using to get the values for the set of radio buttons created or updated.  if I do not put this in an observe({}) the buttons reset to original values, but I do get a list of three values returned from the module.  Pushing a radiobutton  sends a new list of three, but immediately the buttons are reset.  If I place it inside the observe({}) i get no output, but the buttons act correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with Modules. The variables are always kept within the modul and are not visible outside. You can go around with shinyjs. 
Also about you problems with callModule just place a call of it in the server function and it works alright.
Please look at my code below.

**global.r**

```
library(shinyjs)

questListInput <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)

  uiOutput(ns("c1"))

}

questList <- function(input, output, session, q, l) {


  ###This function requires the type of question to be specified

  #  ns <- session$ns

  output$c1 <- renderUI({
    lapply(1:nrow(q),
           function(i) {

             createLabel <- function(name,j) {
               paste0(name,": ",q$Element.Question[j],sep = "")
             }

             labelQ <- createLabel(q[i,]$QID,i)


             createOptions <- function() {
               as.matrix(q[i,5:length(q)])
             }
             tagList(
               tags$hr(style="border-color: darkblue;"),
               h4((paste0(labelQ))),
               radioButtons(session$ns(paste0(l,i)), "Please Select:", choices = c(createOptions()))
             )
           }
    )
  })

  answer <- NULL

  observe({
    lapply(1:nrow(q), 
           function(i) {
             answer[[paste0(l,i)]] <- input[[paste0(l,i)]]
             runjs(paste0("Shiny.onInputChange(",session$ns(paste0(l,i)),",",input[[paste0(l,i)]],");"))
             #input[[paste0(l,i)]] 
             # print(answer)
           }
    )
  )
  })
  print("Inside the Module")
  # print(input$c1)
  # return(
  #  list(
  #    answer1 = reactive({paste0(l,1)})
  #  )
  # )
}
```

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(fullcalendar)

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidRow(
    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    questListInput("occList1")
  )
)
```

**server.R**

```
questionSet <<- read.csv("./data/QuestionSet.csv")
occQuestSet <- questionSet[questionSet$Category == "Occurrence",]

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  callModule(questList,"occList1",occQuestSet,"Occur1")    

  output$answerseT <- renderText(answerSeto1())
  observe({
 #use grep to find all input variables with neames beginning with occList1
    inputNames <- names(input)[grep("^occList1",names(input))]
    #collect the values of variables found previuosly and save them in a vector
    inputList <- unlist(lapply(inputNames,function(id){input[[id]]}))
    #altrenativly selectList <- setNames(unlist(lapply(listNames,function(id){input[[id]]})),listNames)
    #for a named list
    #print vector
    print(inputList)
    })
})
```

Comment: I will give this a try.  What I cannot figure out though is why we can use return to get variables out, but I cannot seem to create a variable that will contain the input values.  Why is this not possible?  I have other modules that I have been able to pass out input values through return.  Why not in this case?

Comment: I suspect there is an error in the ui.R?  I cannot find a package called fullcalendar on CRAN, or anywhere else.  Should this be library(shinyjs)?

Comment: A final question.  I need access to the set of n question results.  The module creates a set of n radio buttons.  While the shinyjs function outputs the set of values, the obseveEvent can only access them one at a time.  I need a vector of these values to use in the rest of app.  This is just an example and does not show that requirement.

Comment: Sorry you can ignore the fullcalendar. It was left from another example

Comment: The input variable including all its elements  is available in all reactive contexts such as reactive,  observe or render functions

Comment: Do I have to access them one at a time the way you did on the print() statement?  I cannot get a text string to work that allows for `occList1-Occur1n` instead of asking for each one at a time.

Comment: I changed the observeEvent in the server to a observe to show you how you can access the varibles dynamicly

Comment: Thank you.  It works in my example, now testing in the main app.  Interesting to see what you had to do to make the list of answers accessible.

Comment: I can't emphasize enough how much this approach should be avoided. If you're going to work this hard to get around the safeguards that modules put up, just don't use modules at all and use regular functions to modularize your app. Or better yet, use modules, and return reactives or lists of reactives as my answer does.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot figure out how to make this dynamic so that it I can access n radiobuttons, and get the values of each.
I have tried to use this to access it but even though it replicates the input$`occList1-Occur11` in the print statement above, it will not access the value.

```
observeEvent({input$`occList1-Occur11`},
{
aa <- noquote(paste0("`occList1-Occur1",1,"`"))
bb <- (eval(noquote(paste0("input$",aa))))
print(get(bb))
})
```

aa returns `occList1-Occur12`
bb returns input$`occList1-Occur12`
but the print statement errors out.

Answer (score 0):

Your module needs to *return* either:

1. a reactive expression that returns a list of the answers
2. a list of reactive expressions, one for each answer

The former is a little easier to work with if you are only going to be doing operations on all of the answers at once. The latter has the advantage that you can have downstream reactive expressions and observers react to specific questions (i.e. downstream reactives won't be triggered by changing answers to questions they don't care about, only the answers they've actually read).

An example of 1:

```
questList <- function(input, output, session, q, l) {
  ...

  # Return a reactive expression that yields a list of all answers
  return(reactive({
    lapply(1:nrow(q), function(i) input[[paste0(l, i)]])
  }))
}
```

You would use this like so (from server.R):

```
function(input, output, session) {
  answers <- callModule(questList, "occList1", occQuestSet, "Occur1")

  output$answerSet <- renderPrint({
    lapply(answers(), print)
  })
}
```

An example of 2:

```
questList <- function(input, output, session, q, l) {
  ...

  # Return a list of reactive expressions that yield a scalar
  return(lapply(1:nrow(q), function(i) {
    reactive(input[[paste0(l, i)]])
  }))
}
```

You would use this like so (from server.R):

```
function(input, output, session) {
  answers <- callModule(questList, "occList1", occQuestSet, "Occur1")

  output$answerSet <- renderPrint({
    lapply(answers, function(answer) {
      print(answer())
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Joe, this is more what I was looking for.  However, I do not want an output$ variable, The results will not be displayed by used for other purposes.  I did not think to put the lapply in the return statement itself.  I was trying to create a variable that I could pass to the return statement.  essentially, do I have to pass the inputs to an output and use it form there?